# how to use jquery.ON() just on elements with specific data-attribute ?

Tags: jquery

How can I use jquery.on event just on elements that have specific data-attribute ?

for example :

```
$(document).on( "click", "ELEMENTS WITH DATA-GOOD", function() {
      console.log("good");
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

By using [has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

```
$(document).on( "click", "[attribute]", function() {
    console.log("good");
});
```

Comment: but what if you dont mind about the value ?
if the element have the attrname is ok...

Comment: @mashiah: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('*[data-attribute="ELEMENTS WITH DATA-GOOD"]').on( "click", function() {
          console.log("good");
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$(document).on( "click", "[attr]", function() {
    console.log("working");
});
```

For more CSS attribute selectors see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors